# Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') How to solve this?

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, flume

While doing Twitter sentiment analysis i come across this error despite searching for extensively for three days for the solution i couldn't get any solution.

Error

```
hive> select * from load_tweets;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@5a82bc58; line: 1, column: 2]
Time taken: 1.698 seconds
hive>
```

Here is the Table creation

```
hive> create external table load_tweets(id BIGINT,text STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe' LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets'
    > ;
```

I am using  Cloudera Json serde version

```
json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I have checked jar file is properly added in hive class path.

Database:
http://freetexthost.com/ik4jyogkfm
This is database fetch by flume.

I am referring this article for the data fetching 
https://acadgild.com/blog/streaming-twitter-data-using-flume/

Comment: Open your JSON files.... They aren't proper json or are not single line entities that Hive requires

Comment: By the way. https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example

Comment: Your JSON data seems to be in error. Post the data you are using.

Comment: I have added the link to the database fetch output text.